# Manual query Ms sql

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm using ms sql server with php and I needing to know what I'm doing wrong, because I'm not getting any data from the database. I know that I'm connected and I know that the columns are the correct name as well as the form name. When I dump the results it says resource(6) of type
(mssql result).

Here's my query.

```
$query = "SELECT *
FROM [ERCOT_Data].[dbo].[TDSP_ESIID]
WHERE ADDRESS LIKE '%$house_num%'
  AND ADDRESS LIKE '%$street%'
  AND ZIPCODE LIKE '%$zip%'
  AND CITY LIKE '%$city%'";
```

I've also tried it like this

```
$query = "SELECT *
FROM [ERCOT_Data].[dbo].[TDSP_ESIID]
WHERE ADDRESS LIKE '$house_num%'
  AND ADDRESS LIKE '$street%'
  AND ZIPCODE LIKE '$zip%'
  AND CITY LIKE '$city%' ";
```

Comment: Run the query through whatever software you use to manage your database. First confirm that data matches your query

Comment: Have you profiled the query and executed it directly on SQL Server? do you get any results? How do you specify the parameter values? e.g for $house_num?

Comment: Yes if I manually put in data from Sql manager studio I get the result I want. Is there something wrong with my query string?. $house_num is a variable coming from a form input.

Comment: How do you pass the values to these parameters? I am not sure of PHP but in .net SqlClient the parameters names start with `@`.

Comment: I'm not following do you mean where am I getting the values for my variables? I'm using php and I'm getting the value of my post data from specific fields.

Comment: If your talking about manual yes I do use the @ symbol to specify a var

Comment: What do you get with `ECHO $query;` ? Does your query look right ?

Comment: What everyone is asking is to EDIT your post and show us the Final query that you get i.e after the PARAMETERS are replaced with ACTUAL VALUES. Cause the query looks fine.

Comment: One more thing are you sure you need to check Address twice? `WHERE ADDRESS LIKE '%$house_num%' AND ADDRESS LIKE '%$street%'`, and that to with AND?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!

It's better to put the PHP variable out of string like this

```
$query = "SELECT *
FROM [ERCOT_Data].[dbo].[TDSP_ESIID]
WHERE ADDRESS LIKE '".$house_num."%'
  AND ADDRESS LIKE '".$street."%'
  AND ZIPCODE LIKE '$".zip."%'
  AND CITY LIKE '$".city."%' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$query = "SELECT *
FROM [php].[dbo].[TDSP_ESIID]
WHERE ADDRESS LIKE '".$house_num%'."
AND ADDRESS LIKE '".$street%'."
AND ZIPCODE LIKE '".$zip%'."
AND CITY LIKE '$city%' ";
```